# Sliders in Windows Store app ListView are moving on their own accord

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, slider, windows-store-apps

I've databound some Items to my listView with this XAML:

```
        <ListView x:Name="itemListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Slider Value="{Binding Intensity}" Width="300" Tag="{Binding Name}" />        
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

And this C# code:

```
        public static ObservableCollection<PoliticalRegion> GetRegions()
        {
            ObservableCollection<PoliticalRegion> politicalRegions = new ObservableCollection<PoliticalRegion>()
                {
                    new PoliticalRegion() {Name = "Algeria", Intensity = 0},
                    new PoliticalRegion() {Name = "Angola", Intensity = 0},
                    new PoliticalRegion() {Name = "Benin", Intensity = 0},
                    new PoliticalRegion() {Name = "Chad", Intensity = 0},
                    new PoliticalRegion() {Name = "Cote_d_Ivoire", Intensity = 0},
                    new PoliticalRegion() {Name = "Djibouti", Intensity = 0},
                    new PoliticalRegion() {Name = "Egypt", Intensity = 0},
                };
            return politicalRegions;
        }
       itemListView.DataContext = GetRegions();
```

When I run this and move a few of the sliders, some of the other sliders move sporadically on their own accord. Why is this??

Comment: do you mean you have other sliders too..if yes can you post xaml code of any of those slider..

Comment: Okay, so I'm not 100% sure, but I believe this has to do with the ListView Virtualizing the item containers (and, subsequently, DataContexts). Try changing the ListView's ItemsPanel to a StackPanel. This mean you will lose virtualization, which could be bad if you are listing every single country and/or region, or are targeting low-level devices as well. You can also try changing the virtualization mode.

Comment: @Nate You're actually correct. The ListView virtualizing the ItemContainers caused the problem. I was able to walkaround this by putting the ListView in a ScrollViewer hence disabling the ListView's virtualization. The listView items aren't much thus the performance impact is minimal. Thanks

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and mark it correct for future questers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListView virtualizing the ItemContainers caused the problem. I was able to walkaround this by putting the ListView in a ScrollViewer hence disabling the ListView's virtualization. The listView items aren't much thus the performance impact is minimal.

Here is the updated XAML.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListView x:Name="itemListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Slider Value="{Binding Intensity}" Width="300" Tag="{Binding Name}" />        
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```